# DIY BioTile for Living Wall

Tags: shade

I live in a sunny place and would like to build a green wall of some sort to block the sun and provide some shade.

I read an article that described one method of construction, with the following image:
[image]

I understand all of the materials except for the *BioTile*. Is there a DIY way to make your own substrate, or an inexpensive alternative suitable for a vertical garden?

Comment: I know that I and, possibly, some building codes would like to see an impermeable membrane like pond liner between the drainage mat and the backer board as well as a drain at the bottom just in case

Comment: I would venture to speculate (with no research into what the maker may or may not admit to) that the biotile is dense rockwool or similar "rooting substrate" as might be seen in a hydroponics system (which this seems to be) encapsulated in a plastic case (hopefully recycled) to provide structural support for convenient handling and to reduce evaporative losses. If not purchasing that particular system, **other means might be more easily managed for a DIY arrangement** (*i.e.* the typical several rows of gutter dripping into each other, holding whatever root substrate and rows of plants.)

Comment: @Ecnerwal Yes, this is what further research has me to believe is the case. I'm not too familiar with the rockwool material and was wondering if I can purchase it, as it seems to be pretty niché, as far as I can tell. Also seems like there might be some toxic/carcinogen worries when working with the material? are these assumptions correct? do you know of suppliers? Thanks!

Comment: Rockwool is a common insulation material. Any building supply has it, typically. Any hydroponic growing supply place probably also does, if you care to think theirs will be in any way different. Other than "don't breathe loose fibers" I'm not aware of any health issues. No doubt California thinks it causes cancer, but California thinks everything causes cancer, as far as I can tell, to the point that Proposition 65 warnings are "the boy who cried wolf" and thus useless, IMHO. Use gloves and a mask when cutting it - in use, wet and full of roots, it won't be a problem. Or use something else.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for taking the time to answer. sounds like it's just like working with fiberglass then. This is the answer I'm looking for. if you wanna add it as the answer, I'll mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a strong structure you could hang pots like these on.

[image]